# DataReader returns no rows but data is present

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqldatareader

I am trying to get alarm stats by month. Here is my SQL statement

```
SELECT datepart(year,incidentDate),datepart(month,incidentDate) ,COUNT(*) AS CNT 
From alarm_actions,alarm_licenses 
where licType = 'AR' and alarm_actions.alarmNo = ALARM_LICENSES.alarmNo and alarmCount > 0 and
ignoreAlarm = 0 and incidentDate between '5/1/12' and '7/31/14'
group by datepart(year,incidentDate) , datepart(month,incidentdate)
order by datepart(year,incidentDate)
```

When I execute this query in SQL 2008R2, I get 27 rows, but when I use a SqlDataReader in Visual Studios I get no data.  The chartFrom and chartTo are textboxes I use to get the dates.

```
string alarmCount = ("Select datepart(year,incidentDate) , datepart(month,incidentDate),COUNT(*) as cnt From Alarm_Actions,Alarm_Licenses Where licType = 'AR' and alarm_actions.alarmNo = alarm_licenses.alarmNo and alarmCount > 0 and ignoreAlarm = 0 and incidentDate between " + chartFromDate + " and " + chartToDate + "group by DATEPART(YEAR, incidentDate), DATEPART(MONTH,incidentDate) order by  DATEPART(YEAR, incidentDate)");
SqlDataReader dr = data.myDataReader(alarmCount);
while(dr.Read())
{
   //Do something
}
```

Here is the code for myDataReader

```
 public SqlDataReader myDataReader(string mSQL) 
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        SqlCommand myCommand1;
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            //myCommand1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(mSQL, myConnection);
            myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(mSQL, myConnection);

            //=============== 1/26/2012 =============
            //There have been errors running recently. I am increasing the timeout here
            myCommand1.CommandTimeout = 60000;

            myReader = myCommand1.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            //return myReader;
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("An error occurred retrieving the requested data\r\n\r\n" + mSQL + "\r\n\r\n" + e1.Message);
            myReader = null;
            try
            {
                string mSentBy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSentBy"].ToString();
                string mSendTo1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSendTo"].ToString();
                string mSubject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSubject"].ToString();
                string mHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailHost"].ToString();
                string mSignon = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSignon"].ToString();
                string mPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailPassword"].ToString();
            }
            catch { }
        }
        finally
        {
            //myConnection.Close();
            myCommand1 = null;
            //myReader = null;
            myConnection = null;
            //myReader = null;
        }
        return myReader;
    }
```

Thanks for helping me

I was missing ' in the date fields.  Thanks for everyone to took the time to help

Comment: Do you get any exception? Could you please post the whole code, the way you create the Sql Connection, You build the commnad you execute it etc.?

Comment: Please post the code of `myDataReader()` function.

Comment: probably not related to your issue, but it's good practice to specify the date format rather than doing implicit conversion..

Comment: Can you also post how the query looks like in the code so we can see if this is related to a formatting issue?

Comment: I just updated it.  ChartFromDate and ChartToDate are textboxes I use to get dates.  I entered the same dates as the above query

Comment: Do chartToDate and chartFromDate have single quotes ? If not, I think you would need to make it something like ` incidentDate BETWEEN ' " + chartFromDate + " '
    and ' " + chartToDate + " '`. Best thing to do would be print out the value of alarmCount after the values of chartFromDate and chartToDate are assigned and try to run the query in sql server.

Comment: Ah.  It was single ' in the date fields.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but I hope it works for you:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);  

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();  
cmd.Connection = con;  
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT datepart(year,incidentDate), ......";  

con.Open();  

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(dr.Read())
{
   //Do something
}

con.Close();
```